# jQuery plugin for phone number input not working with Angular Directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, intl-tel-input

Using the plugin:

https://github.com/Bluefieldscom/intl-tel-input

I created a simply angular directive:

```
.directive('intlTelInput', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    compile: function(elem, attrs) {
      elem.intlTelInput();
      return function() {};
    }
  };
});
```

And the element:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="info.phone" intl-tel-input>
```

Great, only problem is that the model `info.phone` doesn't update when the input changes. I really don't want to listen for "keydown" and manually do this binding, this seems redundant

Comment: You may have to do that and use `$scope.apply()`. Angular binding will not get updated when you jquery plugin updates the input.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/HTUhcG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There is a new directive called international-phone-number @ https://github.com/mareczek/international-phone-number

Please checkout, any contributions are welcome